# Dwm.exe using too much memory after shifting from windows 8.1 to windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1

I reverted to Windows 8.1 for a variety of reasons. This was one of them but now I am shamelessly thinking of re-upgrading to win10. In windows 8.1, dwm uses around 10 MB of Memory, in general. But, when I upgraded to Windows 10, the memory usage usually floated above 100 MB. One time it crossed 200. I have adjusted my computer for performance (disabling visual effects etc.). I don't know what's going on, why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this batch code to refresh **dwm.exe**. There's will be blank screen for a second.
The **dwm.exe** ram usage will back to normal

**I strongly recommend you close all of your application to prevent program crash before executing**

```
@ECHO OFF 
taskkill /F /IM dwm.exe 
taskkill /F /IM conhost.exe
```